# Where do I find some good questions on graph theory, logic, combinatorics and relations?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, logic, graph-theory

So I am revising for an electronic exam in discrete - mathematics. It's a college lesson and it's demanding. I need some practice tests/ questions that can be answered shortly (true or false , multiple choice , or short answers with numbers) because the exam is short -timed. Is there anyhting available? Even if you post below some good questions from your course it could be useful (i found an old post for example with some true or false in graph theory and I found them useful). I just want to practise

Answer (score 1):

You should see the book Mathematical Circles by Dmitri Fomin, Genkin and Ilia Itenberg. It contains a whole range of problems from the former U.S.S.R and explained solutions to almost all the questions. You should definitely check out that book.